# A list of locally finitely presentable topoi that are not coherent

Tags: ct.category-theory, big-list, topos-theory

**[Coherent topoi](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coherent+topos)** play an important role in topos theory, especially in the interaction with logic. Their most handy characterization is provided by   *Johnstone*. **Sketches, D3.3.1**. Every coherent topos is [locally finitely presentable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+finitely+presentable+category) (*Johnstone*. **Sketches, D3.3.12**), but the converse is not true.

Since I am not aware of many counterexamples to the converse, I would like to make a list of them. Possibly, I encourage you to name examples that pop up in nature, instead of something designed to answer the question.

> Let me list a couple of them, both in **Sketches, D3.3.12.**
>
> - $\text{G}$-$\mathsf{Set}$, for G an infinite group.
> - $\mathsf{Set}^{{\text{Fin}}_{\twoheadrightarrow}}$, where ${\text{Fin}}_{\twoheadrightarrow}$ is the category of finite sets and surjections.

Comment: Probably also the topos $Cont(G)$ of continuous group actions for $G$ a topological group, and infinite to be safe. Maybe a [realisability topos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/realizability+topos) for certain [PCAs](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/partial+combinatory+algebra)?

Comment: And, for completeness, **Sketches** is [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Elephant).

Comment: @DavidRoberts As best I know: coherent toposes are sheaf toposes by definition; I don't think realizability toposes are sheaf toposes.

Comment: @Todd no, almost never I would think. Otherwise they would have a global sections functor and I don't think that happens except in degenerate cases. So any realisability topos that is loc.fin.pres. is a counterexample as desired.

Comment: @DavidRoberts according to Thm 4.6 in Jonas Frey, Characterizing partitioned assemblies and realizability toposes, that is not true, you do have a global section functor.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of a geometric morphism to Set. Of course one has _a_ functor to Set, that's true for any cat with a final object.

Comment: When are realizability toposes cocomplete? Are there any nondegenerate examples?

Comment: @Todd good point. I'm glad I hedged my guess with a 'maybe' ;-)

Comment: Beke shows in [Theories of Presheaf Type](http://faculty.uml.edu/tbeke/presheaf.pdf), Thm 2.1 that the presheaf topos $Psh(C)$ is coherent if and only if $C$ has all finite _fc-limits_, a notion defined in the paper. I wish I had a better sense for when that holds, beyond the fact that if $C$ has finite limits, then it has finite fc-limits.

Comment: @TimCampion I agree with you. Another relevant paper to this discussion is the very recent "On Supercompactly and Compactly Generated Toposes" by Morgan Rogers.

Answer (score 3):

**Claim:** In a locally finitely-presentable topos, the quasicompact objects can be characterized as the quotients of finitely-presentable objects.

**Proof:** Suppose first that $X$ is quasicompact. By local finite presentability, there is an effective epimorphism $\amalg_{i \in I} F_i \twoheadrightarrow X$ where each $F_i$ is finitely-presentable. Because $X$ is quasicompact, there is a finite subset $n \subseteq I$ such that $\amalg_{i \in n} F_i \twoheadrightarrow X$ is an effective epimorphism, so that $X$ is a quotient of a finitely-presentable object.

For the other direction, first note that quasicompact objects are closed under quotients. So it suffices to show that every finitely-presentable object $X$ is quasicompact. Let $\amalg_{i \in I} Y_i \twoheadrightarrow X$ be a cover. Then $X = \varinjlim_{n \subseteq I} X_n$ where $n \subseteq I$ is finite and $X_n$ is the image of $\amalg_{i \in n} Y_i$. Because $X$ is finitely-presentable, it is a retract of some $X_n$. Since $X_n \rightarrowtail X$ is monic, this means that $X = X_n$. So $\amalg_{i \in n} Y_i$ is a finite subcover of $X$, and $X$ is quasicompact.

**Fact:** (cf. Makkai and Reyes Thm 9.2.2) In a coherent topos, the coherent objects (which are in particular quasicompact) form a pretopos.

**Upshot:** One easy obstruction is that in a coherent topos, the terminal object needs to be a quotient of finitely-presentable objects.

**Example:** If $P$ is a poset which does not have a cofinal finite subset, then the presheaf category $Psh(P)$ is locally finitely-presentable but not coherent.

Comment: Hello Tim, it's always a pleasure to see your name under my questions. I upvoted, for the moment it's too early to consider this a sufficient question.

Comment: Sure, I thought since you asked for a list it might be worth getting the ball rolling with one list item.

Comment: You definitely did.

Comment: @KevinCarlson If $P$ admits finite meets then it has a terminal object and so in particular a cofinal singleton subset. I should add my argument for this characterization of quasicompact objects, though.

Comment: @TimCampion Yep, just caught that.

Answer (score 0):

One important example of a non-coherent topos to have in mind is the presheaf topos $Set^{\mathcal F}$ where $\mathcal F$ is the category of finitely-presentable objects in the category of fields.

This example is an illustrative one, because the category of points of $Set^{\mathcal F}$ is the category of fields, so it's tempting to call it the "classifying topos for fields". But this is generally thought to be misleading, basically because $Set^{\mathcal F}$ is not coherent.

There *is* a coherent theory whose models in $Set$ are precisely the fields. It's called the "coherent theory of fields", and if you want to talk about "field objects" in a topos, you will typically use this theory / its classifying topos. But the classifying topos of the coherent theory of fields is not a presheaf topos.

I think this is discussed *somewhere* in the Elephant, and also in Beke's [Theories of Presheaf Type](http://faculty.uml.edu/tbeke/presheaf.pdf).

Comment: (Of course, I'm sure Ivan is well aware of everything I've said, but I like the idea of assembling a list of these things in the abstract.)